# Text display odd in Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext3

I have a display problem of Sublime Text (a source code editor).

Background:

1. A desktop computer running Windows 10, Sublime Text 3
2. Tried different versions of Sublime Text on this desktop computer, with computer restart/power-off, all show the same display problem
3. Another computer using the same version of Sublime Text 3, displays fine.

The display problem only exists with Sublime Text (not any other apps) in this desktop computer:

1. the header bar display odd texts (file names of open tabs)
2. when pressed keyboard shortcut Ctrl + h, it shall pop up a text Find an Replace box. (please see screenshot), in my case, there is a box popped but with no texts displayed.

[image]

Comment: uninstall and Restart your PC and reinstall your Sublime

Comment: @Wasiu, thanks for the comment. I've tried that but problem the same.

Comment: when you uninstall goto program file and delete the residual file belonging to sublime if you see any then download and install the new version

Comment: @Waisu, thanks again. I did tried that, even cleaned up the registry - problem the same..

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved by a directly copy (whole folder) of a portable version of Sublime Text 3 from another computer (#1).

Everything seems working fine and normal (computer #2), including the setting and packages done from the computer #1.